# error al enviar datos desde una interfaz react a nodejs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan');

//SETTINGS
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

//MIDDLEWARES
 app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
 app.use(cors())
 app.use(express.json())
 app.use(morgan('dev'))

//ROUTES
 require('./routes/index.routes')(app)

 module.exports = app
```

**indes.router.js**

```
const ctrl = require('../controllers/index.controllers');

  module.exports = app =>{

   app.get('/', ctrl.index);
   app.post('/registro', ctrl.registro)

  }
```

**controllers.js**

```
const ctrl = {};

ctrl.index = (req, res, next)=>{
  res.json({data: 'json de prueba'})
  console.log('prueba');
}

ctrl.registro = (req, res, next)=>{
 console.log('llego el post')
}

module.exports = ctrl;
```

// al ingresar se ve el json que llega al inicio y en la consola se muestra el `prueba`, pero a la hora de hacer un submit el navegador me pinta esto `Cannot POST /registro`

**este es mi app.js de react**

```
import React from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'jquery/src/jquery'
import './style/index.css'
import './style/formulario.css'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import headerStart from './components/header-start'
import formStart from './components/form-start'

function App() {
 return (
   <Router>
      {/* render index for windows principal */}
     <Route path="/" component={headerStart} />
     <Route path="/" component={formStart} />

   </Router>
 )
}

 export default App;
```

y por ultimo les dejo mi formulario de registro

```
  <form action="/registro" method="POST" className="text-center" encType="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" className="" placeholder="Nombre/s" required></input>
      <input type="text" className="" placeholder="Apellido/s" required></input>
      <input type="text" className="" placeholder="Usuario" required></input>
      <input type="email" className="" placeholder="Email" required></input>
      <input type="date" className=""  required></input>
      <select name="sexo" className="" required>
          <option defaultValue disabled> Sexo</option>
          <option value="hombre">Hombre</option>
          <option value="mujer">Mujer</option>
          <option value="indefinido">Prefiero no decirlo</option>
      </select>
          <input type="password" className="" placeholder="Contraseña" required></input>
          <input type="password" className="" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" required></input>
          <button type="submit" className="btn rounded-pill w-50 btn-outline-primary mt-2">Registrarme</button>
           <footer className="blockquote-footer mt-2">Al registrarse usted esta aceptando 
       <cite title="Source Title"><a href="/" className="font-weight-bold">Terminos y condiones</a> 
     </cite></footer>
                </form>
```

//por algun motivo no llega la solicitud post al servidos, tengo el backend y el frontend por separado, pero no creo que sea ese el problema ya que hice pruebas e interactuan entre rutas si sin ningun problema  les agradeceria si pueden ayudarme la verdad no se que puede ser

//me acabo de dar cuenta que tanto el frontend como el backend se conectan en diferentes puertos, el backend en el puerto 300 y cuando quiero correr react con el comando `npm start` me dice que ya hay un servicio corriendo en su puerto y se cambia automaticamente, tenfra algo que ver eso?

Comment: hiciste la prueba con postman a backend?

Comment: nunca escuche hablar de postman

Comment: eh investigado lo que me dijiste, descargue postman y me tira un 404 no entiendo por que

Comment: Y donde esta la conexión que  haces con el back? En el `HTML` sólo tienes un formulario que apunta a */registro*, pero no se especifica ni url base ni puerto. No por tener especificado ese `form` con los parámetros va a saber donde ir. Has escuchado hablar de [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)? [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)? [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)?

Comment: el backend esta en el puerto 3000 y react en el 3001 pero es eso a lo que voy, estoy buscando alguna manera poder dirigirme a las rutas del puerto 3000 sin tener que estar escribiendo http://localhost:3000/ en todas las consultas, por que una vez en produccion no quiero que mis rutas esten escritas asi

Comment: Simple... variables de entorno es la respuesta entonces

Comment: extrayendo el puerto del servidor con `process.env.PORT` ?

Comment: Sí, puedes tener N variables de entorno para lo que necesites, así sólo te limitas a llamarlas las veces que quieras y en caso de tener que cambiar el valor, lo cambias en el archivo `.env`. [Acá](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html) te dejo una guía

Comment: si, ya entiendo, tengo varias variables de entorno usando, lo que no se es si generando una variable como dices puedo acceder a ella facilmente desde el frontend usando `process.env.nombreDeLaVariable`, eso no entiendo

Comment: La envías como parámetro hacia React en el callback simplemente

Comment: me puedes mostrar un ejemplo?

Comment: Tienes que construir un objeto que contenga tu variable. Algo como `res.send({ baseUri: process.env.MyVariable })`